# Unity Google VR Additional libraries must be imported please upgrade

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Hello I have trouble importing the google vr package in unity , my unity is already updated but this appears 
[image: imgur]

Comment: What Unity version are you using? You can find thus by going to **Help** -> **About Unity** from the Editor.

Comment: hi my unity version is 5.4.1

Comment: Please provide a link to where you got the Google VR library from.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I wanted to update the Cardboard SDK on an old project so I downloaded it from Github and imported the *GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage*.

Every time I press play I have this message that pops. It works fine if I ignore it, but you can also click *Import Package* and it will open the *gvr-5.2-and-5.3-compatible.unitypackage* that's inside the *GoogleVR* folder. Import the content and the message will stop poping.

It looks like a bug thought, because I'm using Unity 5.4.0, so I should not need any compatibility for 5.2 or 5.3.

EDIT:
I just realized that now you also need a special version of Unity to use the GVR SDK 1.0. Right now (9/10/16) it's Unity 5.4.1f1-GVR7.1 available [here](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream). Maybe that's why it was complaining about my Unity version.